# Multivariable: Show the limit is $0$.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I already proved that for $\alpha =1$ the limit doesn't exists. Now I need to show that for $\alpha > 1$ the limit does exists and equals $0$.

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\left|x\right|^\alpha y}{x^2+y^2} \overset{?}{=} 0$$

Any ideas how to show it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have

$$0\le\frac{\left|x\right|^\alpha |y|}{x^2+y^2}=\left|x\right|^{\alpha-1}\frac{\left|x\right| |y|}{x^2+y^2}\le\frac12 \left|x\right|^{\alpha-1}\xrightarrow{(x,y)\to(0,0)}0$$
and conclude by the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Smoooth... Thank you! :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:
\begin{equation}
0\le\frac{\left|x\right|^\alpha |y|}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{\left|x\right|^{2}}{x^2+y^2} \lvert y\rvert \lvert x \rvert^{\alpha-2} \le \lvert y\rvert \lvert x \rvert^{\alpha-2} \xrightarrow{(x,y)\to(0,0)}0
\end{equation}

because $\displaystyle\frac{\left|x\right|^{2}}{x^2+y^2}\le 1$. Where am I mistaken?

Comment: Do you ask if that's a false-proof?

Comment: Yes. If we had an $f(x,y)$ with $f(0,0)=0$ if $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and $f(x,y)=\frac{\left|x\right|^\alpha y}{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$, then my result seems to say that $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ if $\alpha>2$, but the in the "accepted as correct" answer, that result seems to be $\alpha>1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** A useful strategy when we have $x^2+y^2$ in the denominator is to go to polar coordinates, letting $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$.

Comment: We haven't learn to use this method, but I might consider it since I've understood it can come very handy sometimes. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. When we substitute, there is cancellation of $r^2$, and we end up with $r^{\alpha -1}\cos\theta\sin\theta$/\.